# How would I write imapInto using mutable vectors?

Tags: haskell

This is related to this question:

[Don't know where to start with mutable Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478268/dont-know-where-to-start-with-mutable-vectors)

How would I write a function that took values from one vector, transformed them and put the results into a second vector?  More specifically, it should iterate over all the indexes of a source array, and hand that index and the array to a function, then store the result of the function in another array.

I think the signature would look something like this:

```
imapInto :: (PrimMonad m, Unbox a) => (MVector (PrimState m) a -> Int -> a) -> MVector (PrimState m) a -> MVector (PrimState m) a  -> m ()
```

And would be called something like this:

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable MV

...
let dst = MV.replicate 10 0.0 in
let src = MV.replicate 10 1.0 in
imapInto (\src' i -> (src' * 2.0)) dst src
...
```

Which would multiply all the elements in src by 2 and put the results into dst, yielding a state unit.

Comment: The idiomatic way to do this is to use immutable vectors; then this is just a `fmap` (unless I'm misunderstanding you).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a builtin function which do what you want. But with [these](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Mutable.html#g:10) primitives it should be possible to write imperative code for your task. And if it will be general enough, you should be able even use it in pure code with [`create`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#v%3acreate).
I guess it will be something like (just sketch, untested) this:

```
imapInto :: (PrimMonad m, Unbox a) => (MVector (PrimState m) a -> Int -> a) -> MVector (PrimState m) a -> MVector (PrimState m) a -> m ()
imapInto f d s = go 0
    where
        go i = when (i < length d) $ write d i (f s i) >> go (i+1)
```

Your type of mapping function seems weird though. Didn't you mean `a -> Int -> a`? Then the code above will require some little changes.

**UPDATE**

Here is the example of usage, along with updated version of the above function. The least possible tweak was to add `m` type constructor to mapper function:

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as MV
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Control.Monad.Primitive

imapInto :: (PrimMonad m, MV.Unbox a) 
         => (MV.MVector (PrimState m) a -> Int -> m a)
         -> MV.MVector (PrimState m) a 
         -> MV.MVector (PrimState m) a 
         -> m ()
imapInto f d s = forM_ [0..MV.length s - 1] $ \i -> do
    v <- f s i
    MV.write d i v

main = do
    -- Create two vectors
    v1 <- MV.replicate 10 1
    v2 <- MV.new 10
    -- Map v1 into v2 using function mapper defined below
    imapInto mapper v2 v1
    -- Print the source and the result
    uv1 <- U.unsafeFreeze v1
    uv2 <- U.unsafeFreeze v2
    print $ U.toList uv1   -- [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    print $ U.toList uv2   -- [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    where
        -- Mapper reads a value from the vector and multiplies it by its index
        mapper v i = fmap (*i) $ MV.read v i
```

Since you're beginner I tried to be as simple as possible, ask if something is not clear.

As you can see, I took advantage of Louis' comment and used `forM_` function to make `imapInto` even more simpler (`forM_` is `mapM_` with arguments swapped). It now looks like ordinary `for` loop from imperative languages. Also as I said I changed mapping function type from `(MVector (PrimState m) a -> Int -> a)` to `(MVector (PrimState m) a -> Int -> m a)`. This is required because you cannot do much with a mutable vector (it is passed as first parameter here) outside its monad. But inside the monad we can do anything with it, and here we are simply reading `i`-th element and multiplying it by `i`.

Note that in this version of function you can do anything with source vector from inside the mapping function. If you do not require this and you only use `i`-th element in conjunction with `i` itself, you can simplify this even more:

```
imapInto' :: (PrimMonad m, MV.Unbox a, MV.Unbox b) 
         => (a -> Int -> b)
         -> MV.MVector (PrimState m) b
         -> MV.MVector (PrimState m) a
         -> m ()
imapInto' f d s = forM_ [0..MV.length s - 1] $ \i -> do
    v <- MV.read s i
    MV.write d i (f v i)
```

Here mapping function is pure and takes only `i`-th element as first argument, not the vector itself. Also I've generalized this version, so it can map first vector into a vector with another type, so source and destination vectors are not required to be of the same type. This is something which could be done to the previous version, too.

Comment: You might consider using the `|` guard condition syntax; otherwise, `if foo then bar else return ()` is fully equivalent to `Control.Monad.when foo bar`.  But personally, I'd use `mapM_ doThing (enumFromN 0 (length src))`, or something that avoided the explicit loop.

Comment: Yeah, `mapM_` is much better. If I had such task myself I probably used it after some thinking. Comment about `when` is also completely right, I have edited my answer to include it.

Comment: Vladimir, thanks for the answer.  After a few hours of fighting with the type system (I'm new to Haskell, and those battles can go on for days), I can't figure out how to actually use this function.  Could you add to your answer a main function that creates a couple of arrays, and calls imapInto, then prints out one of the elements of "dst".  Thanks.

Comment: Well, I wrote that function looking at your type signature, and now I understand that it is impossible to write something useful (without hacks) with it. I will update my answer shortly with new version of it, with correct type signature.

Answer (score 1):

For you example you don't need mutable vectors at all, you can use `map` or `generate` along the lines of the below untested code:

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as M

double :: V.Vector Int -> V.Vector Int
double = V.map (*2)
```

And if you want to use the index:

```
addIndex = V.imap (\element idx -> element + idx)
```

After constructing an immutable vector you can use `unsafeThaw` (assuming you know there are no other references to this vector) to obtain the `MVector` in O(1).  So your final "imapInto" could look like:

```
imapInto :: some constraints => (V.Vector a -> Int -> b) -> V.Vector a -> M.Vector b
imapInto op v = V.unsafeThaw (V.imap op v)
```

If you really want your result vector to be allocated prior to calling `imapInto`, instead of during the call then see Vladimir's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have a version of the code that works this way.  It runs too slow, and in the profile it appears that it's spending a lot of time allocating and collecting these arrays as I iterate.  This is an attempt to reuse those arrays and make the code run faster.